# In R, how to draw multiple curves with ggvis?

Tags: r, plot, visualization, ggvis

In R, how to draw multiple curves with ggvis?  Not knowing how, I tried to do it with a for loop,

```
m <- 10
n_max <- 100
n <- seq.int(1, n_max, 1)
s <- matrix(2*(rbinom(n_max*m, size=1, prob=0.5) - 0.5), ncol = m)
x_estimate <- apply(s, 2, function(z) cumsum(z)/seq_along(z))

data <- data.frame(x_estimate, n)
v <- data %>% 
    ggvis(x = ~n, y = ~x_estimate[,c(1)]) %>%
    layer_lines() %>%
    scale_numeric("y", domain = c(-0.5, 0.5), nice = FALSE, clamp = TRUE)
for ( i in 2:m) {
    v <- (v %>% layer_paths(x = ~n, y = ~x_estimate[,c(i)]))
}
v
```

The resultant plot only has 2 curves instead of m=10 curves.   So, somehow the for loop plots overlapping curves.  Any ideas?  More importantly, how to do this properly with `ggvis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure that's how it should be done, and my solution looks a bit clumsy, but it works.

```
v <- data %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~n)
for (i in 1:m) 
{
  v <- (v %>% layer_paths(prop("y", as.name(colnames(data)[i]))))
}
v %>%
  scale_numeric("y", domain = c(-0.5, 0.5), nice = FALSE, clamp = TRUE, label = 'y')
```

Comment: Thanks!  Any hint on why the original plot overlapping curves?

Comment: You are welcome! No idea, honestly, I thought your code should work correctly.